# Centering a div; not sure what to do

Tags: html, css, footer

I've been trying for hours to center a table div on a website I'm creating, and I can't figure it out. I've tried using margin: 0 auto with a defined width, and that doesn't work. I've also 'margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;", but that didn't work either. I'm really not sure what else to try.

Also, I'm trying to fix my footer to stay on the bottom of the page. It'll look great on one page, coming after all the content, but on another page it will be right on top of the content. Should I make another topic for that, or can someone help me out with that in this one?

HTML for the page with the table:

```css
#body {
 background-color: #8AD4E6;
 font-color: #3E3E3E;
 font-family: "Akzidenz Grotesk" sans-serif; 
}

#content {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
}

#header {
 background-color: #6cf;
 margin:           10px;
 height:           120px;
 font-family: "Akzidenz Grotesk" sans-serif; 
 text-align: center;
 color: #4D8B4D;
 border: 2px solid black;
 }
 

 #headerimg {
 border: 2px solid;
 float: left;
 margin: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 }
 
 #sidebar{
 position: relative;
 float: right;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 25px;
   background-color: #6cf;
   border: 2px solid black;
 }
 
 .sideheading {
 text-align: center;
 color: #4D8B4D;
 font-family: "Akzidenz Grotesk" sans-serif; 
 }

 
table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-left: 35%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
 table th {
 font-style: bold;
 }
.female {
 background-color: #FFE6FF;
 }
.male {
 background-color: #D6EBFF;
 }
.uni{
 background-color: #D4FFD4;
}
#name{
 margin-left: 35%;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
}

#navigation {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: inline;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: #6EC66E;
 margin-left: 44%;
 margin-top: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

#navigation li {
 display: inline-block;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #CC6699;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #4D8B4D;
}
#footer {
   position: relative;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #6cf;
   border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Writer's Toolbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="writerstoolbox.css" />
  </head> 

  <body>
    <div id="headerimg">
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Writer's Toolbox header image" />
  </div> 

 <div id="header"> <h1> Writer's Toolbox</h1><h3>All of your writing needs in one place </h3></div>
 
 <div id="sidebar">
      <h3 class="sideheading">
        <!-- <img src="" alt="" /> -->
        <br />
        What are you looking for?
      </h3>
   <p><a href="names.html">Names</a><br>Settings<br>Character Traits<br>Mary Sue Test<br>Plot ideas<br>Title ideas<br>Writing Tips<br>Resources</p>
  </div>
  
 <div id="content">
 <h3 id="name">'A' Names</h3><br>
  <table id="tablename">
   <tr>
    <th>Names</th>
    <th>Alternate Spelling</th>
    <th>Gender </th>
    <th>Origin</th>
    <th>Meaning</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="male">
    <td>Aaron</td>
    <td>Arron, Aaren</td>
    <td>m</td>
    <td>Hebrew</td>
    <td>Exalted, strong</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="male">
    <td>Abbott</td>
    <td>Abbot</td>
    <td>m</td>
    <td>English</td>
    <td>Head of a monastery</td>
  </table>
  </div>
  
 <footer id="footer"> 
  <ul id="navigation">
   <li><a href="writerstoolbox.html">Homepage</a></li>
   <li> | </li>
   <li><a href="names.html">Back to Names</a></li>
  </ul>
 </footer>`
```

Comment: to fix footer you can use [sticky-footer]  http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: Which element are you trying to center ? If it's the `#content`, then it looks  already centered to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have some problems with the globe styling like u style the table and it's element together 
Any way here's the solution in js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/phonexdoda/ze6dddoh/

i changed the #content style to

```
#content {
    width: 1020px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
```

add $tablename style

```
#tablename{
   margin: auto; 
}
```

and last the table styling

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and for the #name

```
#name {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
```

And the footer need this

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #6cf;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I really appreciate the time you took do to this. What do you mean by I have problems with the global styling/table and it's element together?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `text-align: center;` and `vertical-align: middle;` in the `content` class it will try and format the contents of the div to those attributes. These don't apply to the actual div itself.

Create a new div around the `content` div, like `content_container` and apply  `text-align: center;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to the class.

This will center and vertically align your `content` div.